# the opposite of "sub-system"

Tags: word-request

It is very clear for me what "system" and "sub-system" mean. However, I have a context where, ideally, I use the opposite of "sub-system", and I cannot make up my mind which is better:

> super-system
>
> supra-system
>
> *other word*

In other words, if I promote "sub-system" to "system", what would "system" become?

---

Graphically, it would look something like:

> supra-system / super-system / *other* (????)
>
> |
>
> system
>
> |
>
> sub-system

Comment: Why is this about the English language in particular? As a learner, why not establish the names of you hierarchical levels in your own native language and the translate them if you what to describe the system in English?

Comment: 1. The translation could be as dumb as "sistem" - "system". 2. I happen to need to work with documents in the English language.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have some better answer than I had when I posted the question, even though they do not sound symmetrical: sub- vs. super-.

I do not accept it yet, hoping that better answers might appear.

Alternatives:

- upper level system; *not necessarily parent, any number of levels up;*
- parent system; *one level up;*
- upper-level parent system(?!); *one or more levels up (possibly grand-parent or grand-grand-parent...);*
- higher system; *might this this imply physical placement rather than hierarchical placement?*

Comment: Your answer to your own question is hinting at more context. Are you taking about a **hierarchical control system** as described here?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_control_system

Comment: Hierarchical yes, obviously, but not necessarily "control". A train locomotive is a complex layered system, but not really a control system. An electrical distribution network is also a complex layered system, but not a control system. Examples can continue. Of course, there are some control elements embedded, but the primary purpose is different.

Comment: I’m not sure that I agree with your implication that every system is hierarchical, but the words you might use to describe a hierarchy in a system of some sort are many and varied - there is no one way to name each level in the hierarchy. In different contexts different conventions develop. For example, the system for classifying and naming biological organisms uses: kingdom, phylum/division, class, order, family, genus, species. (https://web.stanford.edu/group/stanfordbirds/text/essays/Taxonomy.html)

Comment: I did not even try to imply that all systems are hierarchical. It was far from my intention. It is just that the systems I am talking about now happen to be hierarchical, and I provided examples in that area. I do not attempt to clarify the entire philosophy of what a system can mean. "Engineered" systems are the ones that interest me now (electric / electronic / mechanical / software). But thanks for the interest ;)

Answer (score -1):

Most sources simply use '*system*', '*main system*' or '*larger system*' in a context including *sub-system* as a part. Less often, a term '**major system**' can be found, which sounds closer to what you are looking for:

https://books.google.com/books/content?id=1wu2DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA309&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=oIj3RSC_kb&sig=ACfU3U2o2i4s-YRQ9X4uIn7Oaazt9z1vjw&w=1280

Comment: Your link doesn’t work. Your answer adds little and is not well written.

Comment: Try the link now (I've changed _google.ru_ to _google.com_ - both work for me).

Comment: Now your link takes me to a poorly written fragment of trechnical jargon. I can’t see how this helps.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie: that fragment shows "major-system" opposed to "sub-system".